# Code customization

Tags: javascript, validation

i want my code to be more accurate.Can any one suggest me in writing the following snippet of code more appropriate?

```
<script>

var frmvalidator  = new Validator("SubscriptionForm");
 frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplaySingleBox();
 frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

  frmvalidator.addValidation("usernameReg","req","Please enter your Username");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("usernameReg","maxlen=20", "Max length for Username is 20");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("usernameReg","alpha_s","Username can contain alphabetic chars only");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("usernameReg","req","Please enter your Username");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("usernameReg","maxlen=20", "Max length for Username is 20");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("usernameReg","alpha_s","Username can contain alphabetic chars only");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("fname","req","Please enter your First Name");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("fname","maxlen=20",   "Max length for FirstName is 20");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("fname","alpha_s","Name can contain alphabetic chars only");


  frmvalidator.addValidation("lname","req","Please enter your Last Name");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("lname","maxlen=20","For LastName, Max length is 20");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("email","maxlen=50");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email");

</script>
```

Comment: Code looks fine @Nida Hafeez. is it possible to look at the `Validator()` Object mentioned in the code?

Comment: What do you think is inaccurate/inappropriate about this code?  I agree with @Crystal Paladin, it looks fine to me.

Comment: how can i make the same script compact with JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nida Hafeez,

This will help you alot if you are willing to start using jquery for your next projects: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Also there is a good form validator from jQuery

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: This is almost a link only answer. Can you copy the relevant stuff from the links to this answer?